# Conditional text appending in datatable cell using css

Tags: css, r, text, datatable, format

I have a datatable and want to add a text to certain cells based on a condition in another column.
For this I have used the example dataset mtcars. The column `ordered` indicates whether the spare part has been already ordered or not.

With the `formatStyle` function I can make formatting options based on the column `ordered`.
Here in this example I have overlined and underlined the values in the `mpg` column if `ordered` is TRUE:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(DT)

mtcars %>% 
  head(5) %>% 
  select(1:3) %>% 
  mutate(ordered = c(F,T,F,F,T)) %>% 
  datatable() %>% 
  formatStyle("mpg", "ordered", `text-decoration` = styleEqual(c(TRUE, FALSE), c("underline overline black", "" )))
```

[image]

Now I want to prepend a text within the `formatStyle`-function via CSS command if `ordered` is TRUE.
The text "already ordered" should now be added to mpg (ideally in red, but the colour is not so important), see the example above.
It would be possible to apply the modification in the previous step directly in R, but this is not possible in my use case. The adjustment must necessarily take place in the `formatStyle` function.
You can enter CSS options directly in the `formatStyle` function. (E.g. `text-decoration` is also derived from css).
See https://rstudio.github.io/DT/functions.html and https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/text-decoration for more informations.